# Precompiling JSPs: Is that server specific?

Tags: java, jsp, platform-agnostic, precompiling

Since JSPs adhere to a standard API, can I precompile them in my projects and then deploy the result on any server?

Specifically, I'm using Tomcat, JBoss and WebSphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. If you look at the java source that gets created by the JSP compiler, you'll see that it extends a base class that's proprietary to the container. For example, JBoss 4's servlet container generates JSP classes that extend `org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase`, which is Tomcat and JBossWeb-specific.

So you *might* be able to reuse pre-compiled JSPs between different tomcat-based servers, but even then it might not work.

Comment: +1. Another point is that the compiler itself tends to be a different class altogether - Tomcat uses the Jasper compiler, which need not be the case with other servlet/JSP containers. NB: WebLogic uses the weblogic.appc class to flag off the compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

Since the servlet/JSP engines are different between app servers there could be byte code added that's not portable.

I'd have to write a test to confirm it.  If I have time I'll try it with Tomcat and WebLogic and report back.

Comment: You will be if it expects app server specific JARs to be in the CLASSPATH and doesn't find them.